# What happened to Flexcraft?

Tags: iss, eva

The DSH Flexcraft seems like a great complement to “traditional” EVAs. Interior environment would be “shirt sleeve”. Astronauts could “scratch where it itches”. It would share a common atmosphere (pressure and composition) with the ISS so no pre-breathing would be required (and, potentially) rescue would be facilitated without equalization or airlock.

[image]

Although the design was part of the Deep Space Habitat project. The concept seems to Interface nicely with the Mobile Servicing System (MSS)  on the ISS

[image]

NASA - http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/464826main_SEV_Concept_FactSheet.pdf

An extension of this design approach is the Multi-MissionScience Exploration Vehicle (MMSEV)

[image]
What happened to these concepts? They seem like the way of the future. The way of the future. The way of the future…. (apologies to Aviator)

Comment: I'd guess there simply isn't enough of a gap between what the existing robot arms can do and what a space suited astronaut can do to justify the development and operating costs. It'd be more convenient than a space suit but much less dexterous and probably not much more dexterous than the canadarm. You could probably achieve a similar result with a remotely operated drone with even more convenience and much lower cost

Comment: I can't look at the third picture without thinking, "Open the pod bay doors please HAL".

Comment: @AlanBirtles from what I know you're spot on, plus they developed DEXTRE which is a more dextrous attachment for the SSRMS end effector. https://www.asc-csa.gc.ca/eng/iss/dextre/about.asp

Comment: @AlanBirtles ... the drone could be smaller, safer and cheaper (no life support). It could easily "swap pilots" so tasks could spans shifts without a break. Maybe all the astronauts could stay on the ground.